# Analytical solution to damped harmonic oscillator - Fokker-Planck equation

Tags: fluid-dynamics, probability, oscillators, stochastic-processes

In the paper "Numerical solution of two dimensional Fokker-Planck equations" (available at: https://doi.org/10.1016/S0096-3003(97)10161-8), the authors quote an analytical solution to the damped harmonic oscillator (where there is a typo for the parameter $b$). I have not been able to find this analytical solution anywhere else. It seems a bit weird as other sources state that the asymptotic solution is of the Boltzmann distribution form, but I do not see how the first paper can arrive to this.

Comment: Have you checked Vankampen? The Fokker-Planck equation for damped harmonic oscillator is called Ornstein-Ulhenbeck equation and it can be solved in the Fourier domain using method of characteristics.

Comment: Thank you very much. This made searching for papers a lot easier with the new keywords.